# How to return a query in a MongoDB database by Date, using Mongoose schemes?

Tags: mongodb, datetime, mongoose, search, find

I've trying to create an endpoint in my API which return the youngest and oldest person from my database using mongodb e mongoose.

My database looks like that:

```
{
"message": "Employees list",
"result": [
    {
        "_id": "62562137bd9acaa47a13e2d2",
        "name": "Anakin Skywalker",
        "email": "skywalker@ssys.com.br",
        "department": "Architecture",
        "salary": 4000,
        "birth_date": "1983-01-01T03:00:00.000Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "625873509d27198519c460cb",
        "name": "pedro",
        "email": "pedror@ssys.com.br",
        "department": "Architecture",
        "salary": 700000,
        "birth_date": "1988-01-01T02:00:00.000Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "6258b2bb6f4786b217624c2d",
        "name": "Henrique Skywalker",
        "email": "henrique@ssys.com.br",
        "department": "INfra",
        "salary": 9000,
        "birth_date": "1991-01-01T02:00:00.000Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "6258b3066f4786b217624c31",
        "name": "perycles Skywalker",
        "email": "perycles@ssys.com.br",
        "department": "INfra",
        "salary": 9000000,
        "birth_date": "1990-01-01T02:00:00.000Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "6258c38dca6a1013e80dbd2f",
        "name": "pdsdss Skywalker",
        "email": "perxsd@ssys.com.br",
        "department": "INfra",
        "salary": 9000000,
        "birth_date": "1990-01-01T02:00:00.000Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "625cbdae195853285e21fead",
        "name": "leia Skywalker",
        "email": "lqpwoe@ssys.com.br",
        "department": "Data",
        "salary": 4500,
        "birth_date": "1978-01-01T03:00:00.000Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

And I need a query response like this one bellow:

```
{
  "younger": {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Anakin Skywalker",
    "email": "skywalker@ssys.com.br",
    "department": "Architecture",
    "salary": "4000.00",
    "birth_date": "01-01-1983"},
  "older": {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Obi-Wan Kenobi",
    "email": "kenobi@ssys.com.br",
    "department": "Back-End",
    "salary": "3000.00",
    "birth_date": "01-01-1977"},
  "average": "40.00"
}
```

My connection with mongoDb by mongoose was created like the example bellow:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
require('dotenv').config();

const dataBase = () => mongoose.connect(
  process.env.URI,
  { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
  () => {
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
  }
);

module.exports = dataBase;
```

My mongoose schema looks like:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const User = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    department: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    salary: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    birth_date: {
      type: Date,
      required: true,
    },
  });

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", User);
```

And my model layer is importing the connection file like that:

```
const model = require("../models/app.model");
```

Nonetheless I don't be able to customize the data form and sort it as well. I appreciate any help in advantage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find max or min then filter the array.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { message: "Employees list" }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      younger: {
        $first: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$result",
            as: "r",
            cond: { $eq: [ "$$r.birth_date", { $max: "$result.birth_date" } ] }
          }
        }
      },
      older: {
        $first: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$result",
            as: "r",
            cond: { $eq: [ "$$r.birth_date", { $min: "$result.birth_date" } ] }
          }
        }
      },
      avg: {
        $subtract: [
          { $year: "$$NOW" },
          {
            $year: {
              $toDate: {
                $avg: {
                  $map: {
                    input: "$result",
                    as: "r",
                    in: { $toLong: { $toDate: "$$r.birth_date" } }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/j_h41NR8bPQ)

Comment: Fisrt of all, thanks for the help. I don't know if it's because I'm using a mongoose schema as model, but when I've tried that solution the only response which I received was the message bellow:
{
    "message": "Younger and Older employee found"
}

Comment: @PedrodeAlmeida mongoose is not a problem. It still can use [aggregate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html). Try my mongolplayground belowmy answer and tell me whether the output is what you need or not.

Comment: I need exactly what you mongoplayground has return. I just can't figure out why my request response is returning only the "message" key.

Comment: @PedrodeAlmeida It would be great if you can accept this answer

Comment: Is it what you need @YuTing?

Answer (score 0):

`db.getCollection('').find({}).sort({birth_date:-1})`

This will sort your collection in descending order by `birth_date`